# Printing white-space using recursion

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, whitespace, padding

So I am writing a program which will print a text triangle where I have for loop for printing white-space in that recursive method. I want to get another recursive method that will print white-space without for loop. Right now, I am just using one recursive method which deals with the text however I do not want a looping structure in my method. I know how to do that using for loop which is something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) { //padding
  System.out.print(' ');
} //for
```

However, I am trying to replicate the same thing using recursion.
I was able to come up with my own code but the output is wrong.

```
public static void print(String str, int indent, int leftLen, int rightIdx) {
 //    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) { //this works perfectly fine
//      System.out.print(' '); // i want to do this recursively.
//    } //for

  whiteSpace(indent);
// ....... some more coding that deals with the text

}

public static void whiteSpace(int indent) {
  int index = 0;
  whiteSpaceHelper(index, indent);
 }

public static void whiteSpaceHelper(int index, int indent) {
if(index < indent) {
  System.out.println(' ');
  index++;
  whiteSpaceHelper(index, indent);
}
```

**My program is printing something like this with the recursion method:**

[image]

**The output that i want is this with the for loop:**

[image]

Is it possible to do something like that using recursion. Can anyone please point out the logic bug in my whiteSpace method? I just need pointers that would set me in the right direction. I will provide more details if that can help you help me. Any other improvement or technique would be appreciated.

Comment: `System.out.print`, not `System.out.println`.  `println` will print one space and go to the next line.

Comment: Thank you. How in the world did i over-look that? @ajb Got the exact output.

Comment: It happens.  I've been programming almost 40 years and I still sometimes make dumb typos and then have trouble finding them.